# Restrict installation of iOS app for iphone 4 & iphone 4S only (Retina Display)

Tags: installation, iphone-4, uidevice

I am developing iOS app. I want this app to be installed on ONLY iPhone 4 & 4S having Retina Display (due to requirement of app).

My plan is to add the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in info.plist & set Front Camera as required functionality. So in this way , my app will run only on iphone 4 & 4S . But my app doesn't use Front camera.

So my questions are

1) Is it OK to restrict the app to be installed on ONLY iPhone 4 & 4S ?2) Does APPLE allow my app in Apple Store because my app doesn't use Front camera & still I am mentioning it in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities ?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not an App Store dev, tinkering with the jailbreak side, but I'd say just put a big notice in the description. And the iPad 2 has a front camera sans retina display.